# Pass callback method result with in a non-activity class to android activity class?

Tags: java, android

I need to create twitter fabric re-usable component.my first step to allow login with twitter by simply calling method from a class.

**Code**

**CLASS**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthToken;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.services.StatusesService;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;


public class TwitterAuth {

private String CONSUMER_KEY;
private String CONSUMER_SECRET;
private Context context;
private TwitterAuthClient client;
private StatusesService service;

public TwitterAuth(Context context, String CONSUMER_KEY, String CONSUMER_SECRET) {
    this.CONSUMER_KEY = CONSUMER_KEY;
    this.CONSUMER_SECRET = CONSUMER_SECRET;
    this.context = context;
    configureKey();
}

public void configureKey() {
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(context, new Twitter(authConfig));
}

public void doLogin() {
    client = new TwitterAuthClient();
    client.authorize((Activity) context, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
            final TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            String token = authToken.token;
            String secret = authToken.secret;
            String userName = session.getUserName();
            Toast.makeText(context, "TWITTER EASY LIB TEST :: Done Login With \n Username :" + userName + " \n Token :" + token + "\n Secret :" + secret, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "TWITTER EASY LIB TEST :: failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public void doLogout() {
    Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
}

public void publishTweet(String tweet) {
    service = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
    service.update(tweet, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> tweetResult) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Tweet Updated !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

**Activity**

```
package codelynks.twitter.twitterintegration;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.easytweet.TwitterAuth;

public class CheckLib extends ActionBarActivity {
private Button cus;
private TwitterAuth auth;
private String CONSUMER_KEY = "", CONSUMER_SECRET = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    auth = new TwitterAuth(CheckLib.this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cusbutton);
    cus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            auth.doLogin();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    auth.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
 }
```

Here i will get the result on callback method

```
   public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {} 
                          **or**
           public void failure(TwitterException e) {}
```

How can i pass this result(SUCCESS/FAILURE) to activity CheckLib for doing further actions.?

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set listener for success or failure in your `TwitterAuth.class` and then set this listener in your activity (`CheckLib.class`) to notify you when success or failure, like this:

```
public class TwitterAuth {
private TwitterLoginListener listener;
public void setListener( TwitterLoginListener listener){
     this.listener = listener;    
}

Interfase TwitterLoginListener{
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult);
    public void failure(TwitterException e);
} 
.
. 
.
```

in success and failure method you need to fill listener:

in success method (in TwitterAuth.class):

```
if(listener != null){
    listener.success(twitterSessionResult);
}
```

in failure method (in TwitterAuth.class):

```
if(listener != null){
    listener.failure(e);
}
```

then in your activity set listener:

```
.
.
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
auth = new TwitterAuth(CheckLib.this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
auth.setListener(new TwitterLoginListener{

     @Override
     public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult){
        //login success
     }

     @Override
     public void failure(TwitterException e){
        //login failed
     }
}); 
.
.
.
```

Comment: thank you. yes,there is another way, as @Kelevandos said you can use EventBus.if you search google you can find good librares. by Bus you can register more class(two,three,four,...) and notify them when an Event happen.if this answer helped you, can you mark this answer as accepted answer.

Comment: of course they should register itself on Bus and unregister itself when their work done,one of good usage of Bus is in Service and Activity callBack

Answer (score 1):

If it is a primitive type, like a boolean or a String (ok, this one is not primitive, but still), you can pass it as an Extra in an Intent which you send to the activity.

If it is a more complex object or you do not have `Context` access in your class, try greenrobot EventBus, a pretty cool library created exactly for such situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can use interface  and implement  the interface method from your dologin method


    check my sample

    public interface sampleInterface {
        // you can define any parameter as per your requirement
        public void yourMethod(boolean value);
    }


    public void doLogin(sampleInterface si) {

          public void publishTweet(String tweet) {
           sampleInterface sampleIn;
        service = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
        service.update(tweet, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Tweet> tweetResult) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Tweet Updated !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            si.yourMethod(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                si.yourMethod(false);
            }
        });
        }
    }


    inside your activity class

            public void onClick(View v) {
                auth.doLogin(new sampleInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void yourMethod(boolean value) {
                        //GET your result
                    }
                });
            }
```